# Is traffic shaping for speed tests a legitimate approach?

Tags: networking, internet-speed, traffic-shaping, speedtest

VW recently got into a lot of trouble for designing a car that performed differently when being tested compared to when it was actually out on the road.  This seems a bit analogous to ISPs providing faster speeds to customers while they are running speed tests (detectable by a particular IP address or traffic pattern) than at other times.  However, traffic shaping is widely used by ISPs for traffic management.  Could traffic shaping also be legitimately used to produce good results in speed tests, that don't accurately reflect speeds for other browsing or use (e.g. video chat)?  Are there known instances where this regularly happens?

---

*This could be moved to [Law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com) if needed, but it seems to be a better fit here.*

Comment: I feel that this is opinion based, as the determination of "legitimate for a given purpose" is subjective. That said, and assuming we are talking about the US, the Federal Trade Commission is the only party that might care enough to do anything, but that would be in egregious cases where it was deemed to constitute misleading advertising. The FCC might like to hear about any cases where this occurs, as it may assist them in decision making in future, but US standards for what Broadband is are absurdly low, so unless the diff between test and normal crosses that threshold, they have no power.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can they, but I know for a fact they do - I'm in the industry.

(And, if you think about it, as soon as they do any kind of QoS the tests must give false results).

Here are some links - 
https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/my-isp-is-cheating-on-speed-tests
http://ask.slashdot.org/story/14/10/09/1241236/ask-slashdot-an-accurate-broadband-speed-test

Comment: I wouldn't say that the very existence of QOS indicates that the tests are lying. While during times of stress QOS may prioritize traffic that is less latency tolerant, a standard binary stream down and up should provide a view of the general up/down. QOS priorities are meaningless unless they are preempting other traffic. If the segment is properly provisioned (and that may be a big if) then my tests would be 100% accurate, whilst my neighbor is streaming video from a paid partner.

Comment: No, the existence of QoS does not indicate the tests are lying [ I said give false results, which I think is subtly different], however by managing the traffic in  the network you are prioritsing some traffic over other traffic, which means that not all traffic will perform the same way under cetain loads, which means the results will be false under those load conditions [otherwise why prioritise the traffic at all ]